# Inherit Variables With Swift Classes

Tags: swift, class, inheritance

I am working on a project in swift that involves multiple Swift files, each with a class in them.  My goal is to have some classes that inherit properties from the others.  For some reason, I cannot access any class' variables from any other class.  For example, here is one file:

```
class Enemy {
    var ready = false
    var someVal = 0

    func someFunctions() {
    }
}
```

In another file, I've tried to create a class that inherits from "Enemy"

```
class badGuy: Enemy {
    ready = true  // This doesn't work as I would expect it to

    func badGuyFunction() {
    }
}
```

If I attempt to access the variables `someVal` or `ready` from either class, I am given an error;

```
class randomClass {
    func test() {
        print(Enemy.ready) //This doesn't work
        print (badGuy.ready) // This doesn't work
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried to use `init()` functions in each of the classes, but that doesn't work.  Just to clarify, I'd like to have a base class, then have a subclass whose "type" is the base class, then in the subclass define values for each of the variables the base class supports. `badGuy` should automatically be able to set it's own `someVal`.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I found the error in compiling.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please provide an *actual* problem description. If you get compiler errors, please show those errors.

Comment: Okay.  If I go into `randomClass` and type `enemy.`, `ready` is not offered as an autocomplete.  If I force it, the compiler says "`Instance member ready cannot be used on type badGuy`"

Comment: @Jake3231 Please [edit] your question with this information. The compiler is quite correct – you need *instances* of these classes in order to access instance properties. If you want to access them on the types, then make them `static`/`class` properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close. With just a few minor edits it works as you intend.

Here is the new `Enemy` class, which is almost identical to your original.

```
class Enemy {

    var ready = false
    var someVal = 0

    func someFunction() {}

}
```

The `BadGuy` subclass can set its properties in its initializer.

```
class BadGuy: Enemy {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        ready = true
    }

    func badGuyFunction() {}

}
```

And then you should be able to use them like this:

```
let badGuy = BadGuy()
print(badGuy.ready) // prints `true`
```

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1** occurs because you have to **override** `ready` in the `init` method

```
class Enemy {
    var ready = false
}

class BadGuy: Enemy {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        ready = true
    }
}
```

Stored properties cannot be overridden directly.

---

**Issue #2** occurs because you are calling the **instance** method on the **type**. You need to create instances of the classes.

```
class RandomClass {
    func test() {
        let enemy = Enemy()
        let badGuy = BadGuy()
        print(enemy.ready)
        print(badGuy.ready)
    }
}

let randomClass = RandomClass()
randomClass.test() // prints two lines `false` and `true`
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense!  I don't know how I missed the fact that I was using a type!